# How to remove characters from a csv file using script? step by step execution

Tags: javascript, csv

I've a csv (students.csv) file contain the name of students from a class. For example they are

```
sumith123,manu456,siva789...
```

Now the problem is I want to write a script to remove the characters from their names and I want to keep only the integers in place of their name, that is

```
123,456,789...
```

My question is on which platform/technology I can achieve this? Even if I'm able to write the script I have zero knowledge where I can execute this script? Is shell scripting can be used to achieve this? If yes can anyone explain it from the step 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are operating in a Unix environment, there are many different technologies you can use to do this. From the command line, `awk` and `sed` spring to mind, although if you have `Perl` installed it will do just as good a job.

The following should work by removing letters:

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' inputFile
```

Comment: so in windows we can  achieve it by using powershell?

Comment: You can add [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) or use equivalent PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Javascript code to extract only the numbers from the string

```
const regex = /\d+/gm;
const str = `sumith123,manu456,siva789`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

You will need to look at the console.log to see how to retrieve that values. From there on you can manipulate the data as you see fit.

Comment: friend as i asked in the question rather than the  the script i want to know on which platform i can do this?if it is in powershell how can i access my csv file and how can i save result to a new csv file?

Comment: @SumithChalil you tagged your question as Javascript therefore I gave the answer for Javascript. BTW, Javascript runs in any browser an on the platform that has a browser. There are browsers out there that do not allow Javascript or CSS for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = 'sumith123';
var regex = /\d+/;
var result = name.match(regex)[0];
console.log(result);
```